# jQuery styling/referencing an element after its dynamic creation

Tags: jquery, css

I have a page with a number of feature panels - beneath which I include a button for each of them. The idea is that when the user clicks on a button, the relevant panel is rendered  (with the rest being hidden). I'm working on some JQuery which...

- creates an array from the feature panels - where class = slide-content
- steps through the array, creating a 'button' for each feature panel - #slidecontrol + unique ID
- these link (s within

  s) are then appended to a  set within the page

  when the user clicks a link, the code steps back through the array, turning off those feature panels that arent relevant and turning on the one that is. This code then also attempts to apply a unique style to the link that was clicked on....

... which is where I'm hitting a problem. For some reason I can't reference the previously dynamically created links - Neither using .css() nor .addClass().

My jQuery code:

```
slideArray = $('.slide-content'); //array of slide-content divs
var $ulslidecontrols = $('#slide-controls'); //instance of slides ul
var $indexno 
//step through the array - create a nav button/link for each slide content div
$.each(slideArray, function (index, value) {
    $indexno = index;
    $indexno++;
    $ulslidecontrols.append(
        $("<li><a href='#' class='slide-control' id='slidecontrol " + $indexno + "'>"
        + $indexno + "</a></li>")
    );
});

$('a.slide-control').click(function () {
    var $slide = $(this).attr("id");
    $slide = $slide.charAt($slide.length - 1);

    //step through the slideArray, hiding slide-content not selected and amending
    style of slide-controls
        $.each(slideArray, function (index, value) {
            $indexno = index;
            $indexno++
            if ($indexno == $slide) {
                $('#slidecontent' + $indexno).hide().fadeIn(600); 
                //display slide content
                $('#slidecontrol' + $indexno).css('font-size', '50px');
            } 

            else {
                $('#slidecontent' + $indexno).hide(); //hide slide content
            }
        });
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dan,

use jquery live for any elements added at runtime.

```
http://api.jquery.com/live/
```

i think something wrong here in your code

check what is $indexno is printing and

```
 $('#slidecontent'+$indexno)
```

Comment: Hi Kobe,I'd tried that, though it doesnt seem to help.. replacing ('a.slide-control').click(function () { ... with $('a.slide-control').live("click", function () {

Comment: @dan , check your $indexno once

Comment: Kobe - I've come across the same at the same time.... what a wally!! Cheers Kobe for your assistance. Much appreciated ;)